# Why do I have to type ctrl-d twice?

Tags: python, eof, tty

For my own amusement, I've cooked up a python script that allows me to use python for bash one-liners; Supply a python generator expression; and the script iterates over it.  Here's the script:

```
DEFAULT_MODULES = ['os', 're', 'sys']

_g = {}
for m in DEFAULT_MODULES:
    _g[m] = __import__(m)

import sys
sys.stdout.writelines(eval(sys.argv[1], _g))
```

And here's how you might use it.

```
$ groups | python pype.py '(l.upper() for l in sys.stdin)'
DBORNSIDE
$
```

For the intended use, it works perfectly!

But when I don't feed it with pipe and just invoke it directly, for instance: <sub>[emphasis added to show what I type]</sub>

```
$ python pype.py '("%r\n" % (l,) for l in sys.stdin)'
fooEnter
barEnter
bazEnter
Ctrl DCtrl D'foo\n'
'bar\n'
'baz\n'
$
```

In order to stop accepting input and produce any output, I have to type either <kbd>Enter</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> or  <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd>.  This violates my expectations, that each line should be processed as entered, and that typing <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> at any time will end the script.  Where is the gap in my understanding?

EDIT: I've updated the interactive example to show that I'm not seeing the quoting wim describes in his answer, and some more examples too.

```
$ python pype.py '("%r\n" % (l,) for l in sys.stdin)'
fooCtrl DCtrl DbarEnter
Ctrl DCtrl D'foobar\n'
$ python pype.py '("%r\n" % (l,) for l in sys.stdin)'
fooCtrl VCtrl D^DbarEnter
Ctrl DCtrl D'foo\x04bar\n'
$
```

Comment: Works for me (OS X 10.5, Python 2.5 and 3.2).

Comment: By my experience, the behavior you described is exactly what I would expect - an expectation violation would be just the behavior you expected. The described behavior is what I always got in Linux and Mac OS machines. (Except by the double Ctrl D - I just need to type it once (if on a new empty line) or twice (if the current line has some content).

Comment: @brandizzi: that parenthesized bit is exactly what I'm talking about.  I am also perplexed by the fact that I enter multiple lines before any input gets processed, but that's the lesser question.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I wonder why you got it too, specially because I could not reproduce it. What is your OS? Also, what shell are you using?

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue for some versions of python;  I'll have to work around it.

Comment: As a Final thought: There doesn't seem to be any elegant work-around to the way python's `file.readline` works;  It might be possible to implement a file-like object from whole cloth based on `os.read`, doing the buffering in the right way, and substituting it in when `sys.stdin.isatty()`, but really the cleverest solution is to just use python 3, which doesn't have this behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> is recognized not necessarily as EOF, but as "terminate current `read()` call".

If you have an empty line (or just pressed <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>) and press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, your `read()` terminates immediately and returns 0 read bytes. And this is a sign for EOF.

If you have data in a line and press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, your `read()` terminates with whatever there has been typed, of course without a terminating newline (`'\n'`).

So if you have input data, you press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> twice of a non-empty line or once on a empty one, i.e. with <kbd>Enter</kbd> before.

This all holds for the normal OS interface, accessible from Python via `os.read()`.

Python file objects, and also file iterators, treat the first EOF recognized as termination for the current `read()` call, as they suppose there is nothing any longer. A next `read()` call tries again and needs another <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> in order to really return 0 bytes. The reason is that a file object `read()` always tries to return as many bytes as requested and tries to fill up if a OS `read()` returns less than requested.

As opposite to `file.readline()`, `iter(file)` uses the internal `read()` functions to read and thus always has this special requirement of the extra <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>.

I always use `iter(file.readline, '')` to read line-wise from a file.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use iter(...).  That is exactly what I needed to get the single-Ctrl-D behavior that I want.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is recognized by the terminal device, terminal responds to it by generating an end of file.  Perhaps this will help, from Wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> In UNIX and AmigaDOS, the translation of the keystroke to EOF is performed by the terminal driver, so a program does not need to distinguish terminals from other input files. By default, the driver converts a Control-D character at the start of a line into an end-of-file indicator. To insert an actual Control-D (ASCII 04) character into the input stream, the user precedes it with a "quote" command character (usually Control-V, although on some systems **you achieve this effect by typing Control-D twice**).

Comment: Control-V Control-D *does* give me a `\x04`, but Control-D Control-D doesn't.  where is the extra control d going?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly why the extra CTRL+D (the other answer does a very good job of that though), but this will make it so the input is printed after only a single <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>, but you still need to <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> a second time to exit the script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
DEFAULT_MODULES = ['os', 're', 'sys']

_g = {}
for m in DEFAULT_MODULES:
    _g[m] = __import__(m)

import sys
for x in eval(sys.argv[1], _g):
    print x,
```

Output:

```
[ root@host ~ ]$ ./test.py '(l.upper() for l in sys.stdin)'
abc
def(ENTER, CTRL+D)
ABC
DEF
qwerty(ENTER, CTRL+D)
QWERTY
[ root@host ~ ]$
```

Edit:

`eval` is returning a generator in this case, so possible the first EOF (CTRL+D) ends the reading of sys.stdin, and the second stops the generator that `eval` is producing.

[Generator](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator) - A function which returns an iterator. It looks like a normal function except that it contains yield statements for producing a series a values usable in a for-loop or that can be retrieved one at a time with the next() function. Each yield temporarily suspends processing, remembering the location execution state (including local variables and pending try-statements). When the generator resumes, it picks-up where it left-off (in contrast to functions which start fresh on every invocation).

[Generator Class reference (section 9.10)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: [Generator](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator) - A function which returns an iterator. It looks like a normal function except that it contains yield statements for producing a series a values usable in a for-loop or that can be retrieved one at a time with the next() function. Each yield temporarily suspends processing, remembering the location execution state (including local variables and pending try-statements). When the generator resumes, it picks-up where it left-off (in contrast to functions which start fresh on every invocation).

Comment: I know what a generator is.  `eval` isn't one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the thing being returned by `eval(sys.argv[1], _g)` is a generator.  Try:  `sys.stdout.write(eval(sys.argv[1], _g))`, the write call raises: `TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not generator`