# How to capture Ctrl+D when you have already typed soemthing in raw_input but have not pressed enter yet?

Tags: python, raw-input

I want to support multiple line input for `raw_input`, ctrl+d in the following code works only when I am on an empty (new) line,

Current behaviour:

- when user types `xyz`, then press enter again to get a new line, then ctrl+d.
- when user types `xyz`, then press ctrl+d 4 times, the first three times it has no effect, the 4th time makes it exit the function.

expected behaviour:

when user types `xyz`, then ctrl+d to exit the function(without needing to be on an empty line).

```py
def multi_line_input(prompt=''):
    contents = []
    print('ctrl+d to exit')
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if i:
                line = raw_input()
            else:
                line = raw_input(prompt)
            i += 1
        except EOFError:
            break
        contents.append(line)

    return '\n'.join(contents).strip()


x = multi_line_input('please enter text >> ')
print ('user entered:', x)
```

Comment: *"Currently the behavior is, type xyz, then press enter again to get a new line, then ctrl+d."* That's not the behaviour of your code, it's the behaviour of the user! What happens if you *do* type `xyz` then Ctrl-D?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369170/why-do-i-have-to-type-ctrl-d-twice this answers your question?

Comment: @ranifisch No it did not, for me I have to press it 4 time instead of 2 times.

Comment: This is likely terminal-dependent behavior, as it is your *terminal* that intercepts Control-D and interprets it as a request to *close* standard input, rather than producing a character that *appears* in standard input.